# Convert a string to and unsigned char []

Tags: c++, arrays, cstring, unsigned-char

I currently have a Packet set up like so:

```
struct Packet {
    unsigned short sequenceNumber;
    unsigned short length;
    unsigned char control;
    unsigned char ack;
    unsigned short crc;
    unsigned char data[];
    Packet copy(const Packet& aPacket) {
        sequenceNumber = aPacket.sequenceNumber;
        length = aPacket.length;
        control= aPacket.control;
        ack = aPacket.ack;
        crc = aPacket.crc;
        memcpy (data, aPacket.data, aPacket.length);
    }
};
```

This packet gets converted into a string for encryption and then needs to be taken from its decrypted string form back to a Packet. I am able to do this fine for all of the variables except for the `unsigned char data[]`. I have tried the following with no success:

```
string data = thePack.substr(pos, thePack.length()-pos);
    unsigned char * cData = new unsigned char[data.length()];
    strcpy((char *)cData, data.c_str());
    memcpy(p.data, cData, data.length());
```

where data is the string representation of the data to be copied into the `unsigned char []` and p is the Packet.

This gives the following from valgrind:

```
==16851== Invalid write of size 1

==16851==    at 0x4A082E7: strcpy (mc_replace_strmem.c:303)
```

Even though it cites `strcpy` as the source, it compiles and runs fine with just the `memcpy` line commented out.

I have also tried replacing `memcpy` with `strcpy` with the same result. Any ideas? I feel that it might be due to the fact that data may have not been initialized and there for not have any memory allocated to it, but I thought `memcpy` would take care of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't specified the size of the `data` array.

```
unsigned char data[];
```

This is legal, but rather difficult to use.  The `data` array will follow the rest of the `Packet` structure in memory, but the compiler doesn't know how much space to allocate for it.  So you have to allocate the extra space yourself:

```
size_t datalen = thePack.length()-pos;
void* pbuffer = malloc( sizeof (Packet) + datalen + 1 );
Packet* p = new (pbuffer) Packet;
memcpy(p.data, &thePack[pos], datalen);
p.data[datelen] = 0;
```

What won't work is letting the compiler decide how big a `Packet` should be, either using `new Packet` or a local variable `Packet p;`.  That will end up with no space reserved for `data`.  And no, `memcpy` doesn't allocate memory.

A much cleaner solution would be to use a `std::vector` for your variable-sized data array.

Answer (score 1):

The `char[]` you're allocating is one character too small -- you must leave room for the NULL byte at the end:

```
unsigned char * cData = new unsigned char[data.length() + 1];
```

Use the `strcpy` version to copy the string, so the NULL byte gets copied correctly. Although it might run OK without that +1, there's no guarantee, and sometimes it might crash.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I just tried this and no dice. Any other ideas?